# Changing variable value after time period

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm reasonably new to C++ programming, and I'm creating a game loosely similar to space invaders.

What I want to do is have a bool value, "player.shield" which when is false, after 20 seconds it changes the value back to true.

How will I go about this?

Any help is appreciated :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the platform, libraries you use etc. Generally, even if you can use some more or less asynchronous timers, in games this is usually done differently in a main loop, which deals with all game mechanics in a controlled fashion.

I.e. instead of having possibly dozens of timers which can trigger at any time and in any order, you rather create a function like this:

```
void onGameTick()
{
   DWORD currentTime = ::GetTickCount();

   if (player.shield && currentTime - player.shieldAcquiredTime < 20) {
     player.shield = false;
     // You can also do other things here like trigger a sound effect etc.
   }

   // Do other logic, like move players, enemies, shots etc.
}
```

Then call this function before each screen update or by a timer or whatever.

By using this technique, you make any changes in the game state very explicit, always done in the same order, easily debuggable in a linear fashion, avoid possible multi thread data races etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I tweaked it a little and it worked perfectly :) 

void ShieldDisabled()
{
   DWORD currentTime = ::GetTickCount();
   player.shieldAcquiredTime += 1;

   if ((player.shield == false) && player.shieldAcquiredTime > 2000) 
   {
     player.shield = true;
  if (player.shieldAcquiredTime > 2500)
  {
   player.shieldAcquiredTime = 0;
  }
   }

}

Comment: OK, that's another way how to do it, but you need to make sure it is called on precise intervals, so that the variable is incremented evenly each time. You can then remove the `currentTime` part nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done via the Win32 API function `SetTimer`, where you can register a callback to update values.

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Here's [a link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/) to the c++ timer reference.

1) Set "player.shield = true"

2) Start timer

```
#include <ctime>

inline void timeSec(clock_t sec) 
{
    clock_t start_time = clock();
    clock_t end_time = sec * 1000 + start_time
    while(clock() != end_time);
}
```